# MySQL Workbench connection to local network MAMP server

Tags: mysql, mamp, mysql-workbench

I have MAMP installed on my Macbook Pro retina 13, which is in the same network as my workstation Windows machine. I would like to have MySQL Workbench to communicate with my MAMP server (instead of installing WAMP on this workstation), but I have been getting the `Failed to Connect to MySQL at 192.168.169.101:8888 with user root` and `Invalid for this platform protocol requested(MYSQL-PROTOCOL_SOCKET)` error.

Could this be a firewall issue? I am sure I have the right IP address and correct port, but I cannot get my Windows machine to communicate with my MAMP server.

Comment: How sure are you that you have the right IP address?

Comment: Here is a screenshot: http://puu.sh/5cjtm/511df0aeeb.png

Comment: On my Windows machine for MySQL Workbench, I have Hostname: 192.168.169.101, Port: 8888, Username: root, Password: root

Comment: The screenshot is from your Windows machine to the MBP? If so and it works as expected it means there's no firewall issue, but something with your connection as such. Can you install MySQL Workbench for OS X on your MBP and see if you can connect from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the wrong port number. I will be cognizant of that next time.